# "Problems found loading plugins" in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My Android Studio was working perfectly but today when I open any of my previous projects I get this error:

> Problems found loading plugins

How can I resolve this?

Comment: show your Logcat

Comment: This question appears to have been abandoned, despite requests for clarification, so I am voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

go to Settings-Plugins-IDE Settings and just disable and enable again needed plugins - it will help you.